# Problem with pgpoolAdmin installation

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I got a problem with permissions during installation of pgpoolAdmin(newest version). The problem is when I get to window with main config that should be all okay to move to next installtion step.

The problem is access to two files: *pgpool.conf* and *pcp.conf*. Application says: "Write access denied". I tried "chmod 777" on those config files and "chown apache config_file_name" nothing works. I still see "Write access denied". Whole pgpool application is in /var/www/html/pgpoolAdmin. Location of those two files is /usr/local/etc/. I'm using Centos 6.5.

Sorry for no pictures but I have bo permission to upload

Comment: What OS are you on? Any chance you have AppArmour (Ubuntu) or SELinux (Fedora)? Check `dmesg`.

Comment: Centos 6.5 on virtual machine

Comment: application just cannot access two files which must be accessible to go to next step of installation...

Comment: I checked dmesg... not found any errors

Comment: Show output of: `getenforce` please. Also try running the `SELinux Troubleshooter` (otherwise known as "selinux alert browser"), command line `sealert`

Comment: [root@cvc]# getenforce
Enforcing

Comment: OK, and if for testing purposes only you run: `sudo setenforce 0` and re-test... ?

Comment: it found both files :D

Comment: For now what is main reason that application didn't see those files?

Comment: sealert found this problem... shows solutions for both files...

Comment: I should change label of pgpool.conf to one from the list:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have SELinux enabled, and your policy doesn't allow Apache to write to those files.

Adjust the policy, relabel the files, or (not recommended) disable SELinux.  The `sealert` can help provide guidance.

Comment: all understood but whal file label I should choose?(I Can send list duggested by selinux)