# Pgpool - semanage config files - which filetype should I choose?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, installation, pgpool

Reffering to problem with pgpool installation :
[Problem with pgpoolAdmin installation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69717/problem-with-pgpooladmin-installation/69727#69727)
I had a problem with non running pgpooladmin(installation files permission was wrong).
I must change file label of files: "pgpool.conf" and "pcp.conf". I checked those files with ls -Z and saw this:

> [root@cvc etc]# ls -Z
>
> **-rw-rw-rw-. apache root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   pcp.conf**
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0       pcp.conf.sample
>
> **-rw-rw-rw-. apache root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   pgpool.conf**
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   pgpool.conf.sample
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0 pgpool.conf.sample-master-slave
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0  pgpool.conf.sample-replication
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   pgpool.conf.sample-stream
>
> -rw-rw-rw-. root   root system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0   pool_hba.conf.sample

Communicate from SELinux tolds:

> You should change label of pgpool.conf with
> **semanage fcontext -a -t FILE_TYPE 'pgpool.conf'**,
> which FILE_TYPE is one of below:
> squirrelmail_spool_t,
> dirsrvadmin_config_t,
> afs_cache_t, httpd_t,
> user_cron_spool_t,
> httpd_lock_t,
> dirsrv_config_t,
> httpd_tmp_t,
> dirsrvadmin_tmp_t,
> httpd_cache_t,
> httpd_tmpfs_t,
> httpd_squirrelmail_t,
> puppet_tmp_t,
> dirsrv_var_log_t,
> zarafa_var_lib_t,
> dirsrv_var_run_t,
> httpd_var_lib_t,
> httpd_var_run_t,
> httpd_nagios_rw_content_t,
> passenger_tmp_t,
> httpd_nutups_cgi_rw_content_t,
> httpd_apcupsd_cgi_rw_content_t,
> httpd_dspam_rw_content_t,
> httpd_mediawiki_rw_content_t,
> httpd_squid_rw_content_t,
> httpd_prewikka_rw_content_t,
> httpd_smokeping_cgi_rw_content_t,
> passenger_var_run_t,
> httpd_openshift_rw_content_t,
> httpd_dirsrvadmin_rw_content_t,
> httpd_w3c_validator_rw_content_t,
> cluster_var_lib_t,
> cluster_var_run_t,
> httpd_user_rw_content_t,
> httpd_awstats_rw_content_t,
> root_t,
> httpdcontent,
> httpd_cobbler_rw_content_t,
> httpd_munin_rw_content_t,
> cluster_conf_t,
> cluster_tmp_t,
> httpd_bugzilla_rw_content_t,
> httpd_cvs_rw_content_t,
> httpd_git_rw_content_t,
> httpd_sys_rw_content_t,
> httpd_sys_rw_content_t
> Next you have to execute:
> restorecon -v 'pgpool.conf'

When I try to change filetype it tolds me that choosen one is wrong... which filetype should I choose?

Comment: "tolds me that choosen one is wrong". The error message being?

Comment: `[root@cvc etc]# semanage fcontext -a -t system_u 'pgpool.conf'`
/usr/sbin/semanage: Type system_u is invalid, must be a file or device type

Comment: It's first time when I'm doing something like this so I don't know which type should I choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution founded:** 
[image: Image of the bug]

To repair this issue I must execute this comand:

> chcon -t httpd_user_rw_content_t pgpool.conf

and

> chcon -t httpd_user_rw_content_t pcp.conf

[image: Image of changed files labels]

then pgpooladmin will show that those files are writable and will allow to click "Next" to install pgpoolAdmin.
Yay Cheers :D